# How to get pandastable on PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python

I tried to get `pandastable` on `PySimpleGUI` but it shows me `grid vs pack` error.
any one tried to get it right?

I searched lot but not getting it work.

Comment: I don't think they can work together, although both based on tkinter.

Comment: then can i merge tkinter with pysimplegui

Comment: You can use tkinter code in PySimpleGUI script, but lot of limits.

Comment: i have working pandastable in tkinter any guide join that with PySimpleGUI .

Comment: All elements of PySimpleGUI come from tkinter basic widgets, any new widgets or new classes in  Pandastable not supported.